# Disable scroll of a subview in a UIScrollView

Tags: ios, swift, objective-c, uiscrollview

I have a video player view on the top of the scroll view, and I added swipe vertically to adjust volume and brightness feature.

The problem is when I swipe in the player view to adjust the volume, the scroll view scrolls as well, how can I prevent it?

Comment: What if you did `yourScrollView.isScrollEnabled = false` ?

Comment: I do need the view to scroll in general, just want to keep it still while I'm adjusting the volume.

Comment: How does the user scroll in your scroll view ? If the vertical gesture is to adjust the video, what would the user do to go down the list then ? Unless there are some spaces between the videos in your scrollview where the user can swipe to scroll vertically.

Comment: Hi Shawn, it is a game infomation page with a game trailor video attached to the top,  just like those youtube videos in portrait mode, the difference is when you scroll down in Youtube, the video stays the top of the screen, but I want my video to move down with the scroll view while I'm scrolling from outside the video player view, when I'm "scrolling" from inside the video player view, I want the brightness/volume to be adjusted.

Answer (score 1):

This could probably work for your use case.

I am assuming you added a `pan gesture` on your video view and so in your action handler, you could disable the scrollview from scrolling when the gesture's state is `.began` or `.changed` and re-enable it for any any state such as `ended` or `cancelled`

Here is how I did that:

```
@objc
func didPan(_ panGesture: UIGestureRecognizer)
{
    scrollView.isScrollEnabled
        = panGesture.state != .began && panGesture.state != .changed
    
    /* The above is the same as these lines of code
    if panGesture.state == .began || panGesture.state == .ended
    {
        scrollView.isScrollEnabled = false
        return
    }
    
    scrollView.isScrollEnabled = true
    */
}
```

Here is an example of what happens with this code:

1. When I pan on the video, it shows a label and stops the scroll view from moving
2. When I pan on another view inside the scrollview but outside the video region (in the yellow region), it is active

[image: AVPlayer in UIScrollView pan gesture on UIView ioS Swift]